# Angular - CORS Origin - External Identity Server 4 instance

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cors, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way for anyone developing an Angular app locally to connect to an externally hosted Identity Server instance without hitting CORS rules that Chrome is spewing out (not Identity Server).

I was thinking we could use a proxy.config and host it with node so that it redirects **localhost:4200/dev/identity** to our hosted Identity Server instance. But it's not that simple, it get's a discovery document and then several redirects.

This is quite a common scenario yet I can't find a thing online, which tells me I'm either doing it wrong or there is a far simpler solution. ***Can anyone point me in the right direction or have a similar proxy file which hits all the well-known end points!?***

FYI here would be my proxy.config

```
{
  "dev/identity": {
    "target": {
      "host": "ids-cloud.com",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 443
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  },
  "/dev/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration": {
    "target": {
      "host": "ids-cloud.com",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 443
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  },
  "*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

The last * is used for sending calls out to my API.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy.config with node is a good idea, this is how I do it, but there's no need to redirect. Call you the identity server with http(s) and returns its response to angular.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I will document how I managed to do this below!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that the best way to do this was to have the server return a cross origin header for our development environments.

When the angular client app calls out the server returns a header which prevents Chrome from complaining about CORS. In which case I didn't need the proxy class, and all the developers can use the same dev instance.

You can do this in Azure via App Service CORS options or if you want, you can develop it as a part of Startup in an API.